# Error with my annyang program

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I am trying to implements this annyang program:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/1.1.0/annyang.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (annyang) {
        // Let's define our first command. First the text we expect, and then the function it   should call
        var commands = {
            'show tps report': function() {
                $('#tpsreport').animate({bottom: '-100px'});
            }
        };

        // Add our commands to annyang
        annyang.addCommands(commands);

        // Start listening. You can call this here, or attach this call to an event, button, etc.
        annyang.start();
    }

    else{
        alert("Error alert");
    }
 </script>
```

The problem is that I got "Error alert" message, and I didn't figure out the reason?

Comment: Do you have more details about this "Error alert" message?

Comment: annyang is `undefined`, use the "browser console"

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jJ68t/

Comment: Can you post the full html?

Comment: @JaredFarrish it works fine for you, but not for me. Reason being - it's being run before the page is completely loaded. I get the Error alert message from your fiddle.

Comment: @datashaman - The reason it probably doesn't work seems to involve which browser is being used: Chrome, ok, Firefox/IE, not ok. Scripts are not loaded asynchronously unless you tell them to, so the code should work if it does work. Perhaps there is some kind of feature detection going on.

Comment: OK, but how to resolve this problem ( it's being run before the page is completely loaded.)?

Comment: @user1444393 - It's a browser support issue, you can't resolve it if the browser doesn't have the support. See Guilherme's answer.

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Answer (score 3):

`SpeechRecognition` not work in Firefox (Desktop version 29), see:

```
(function () {
    var b = this;
    console.log(b.SpeechRecognition); // undefined
    console.log(b.webkitSpeechRecognition); // undefined
    console.log(b.mozSpeechRecognition); // undefined
    console.log(b.msSpeechRecognition); // undefined
    console.log(b.oSpeechRecognition); // undefined
}).call(this);
```

See in https://www.talater.com/annyang/ (Fixed footer), shows:

[image: fixed footer]

`SpeechRecognition` requires browsers like "Google Chrome"

Answer (score 0):

You should edit annyang library your layout url.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/2.6.1/annyang.min.js"></script>
```