# How to grab the "response" of the server using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please have a look at the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/annyang/1.1.0/annyang.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        if (annyang) {
                // Let's define our first command. First the text we expect, and then the function it should call
                var commands = {
                'hello': function() {
                    alert("Hello!");
                }
            };

        // Add our commands to annyang
        annyang.addCommands(commands);

         // Start listening. You can call this here, or attach this call to an event, button, etc.
       // annyang.start();
        }
</script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <button onclick="annyang.start();">Start</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript code sends the data to a external server and get the response. The imported JS file can be found from here - https://github.com/TalAter/annyang

My question is, how can I view the "response" which I get from the server?

Comment: downvoters should comment.

Comment: You could use one of many tools, either F12 in the browser, all modern browsers would allow for you to see the response. Or if you wish you could use Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com) to see the response.

Comment: @Qpirate: Thanks for the reply, I need to use the response in my code, so I should grab it in code.

Comment: Press F12 and like Quentin told you, look in there for see the reply. Also, about Annyang, look this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871046/error-with-my-annyang-program

Comment: Are you sure there is a server involved?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do why do you need to see the server response?

Comment: @vimes1984: This is speech recognition. I need to see the "confidence score"

Answer (score 0):

To see the results returned in the console, turn on debug mode by adding this:

```
annyang.debug();
```

Alternatively, to capture all recognized text in a function, simply add a catch-all function

```
annyang.addCommands({
  '*transcript': function(transcript) {
    console.log(transcript);
  }
});
```

P.S. I think you want to uncomment your start() command.

Comment: Hi, thank you. How can i get the 'confidence score' ?

Comment: The goal of annyang is to encapsulate the inner workings of the browser's SpeechRecognition engine, and its various issues and provide you with an easy to use API to interact with it. If you want direct access to the raw response from Google, you will have to work directly with the browser's implementation of webkitSpeechRecognition, and not a library.